# asio program exit befor completing async_write

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

I am making  some tests with boost Asio, and i don't understand why the handler of the async_write function (witch is the lambda function) does not get called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio;

int main() {
    io_service service;
    std::string str = std::string("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n ......");

    ip::tcp::acceptor my_acceptor{ service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), 6767) };
    ip::tcp::socket my_socket{ service };
    my_acceptor.async_accept(my_socket, [&my_socket, str](boost::system::error_code) {
        std::cout << "connected " << std::endl;

        async_write(my_socket, boost::asio::buffer(str), [&my_socket](boost::system::error_code, std::size_t) {
            std::cout << "Data written" << std::endl;

        });

    });

    service.run();
}
```

the "Data written" never appear and the message is not sent to the client 
what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: formatting and avoiding useless manual memory management are your first lines of defense

Answer (score 0):

The code runs fine for me.

Are you running with sufficient privileges to listen on port 80?

Are you sure nothing else is listening there?

Try

- running on a different port (say, 6767 instead of 80)
- printing the message of `ec`

E.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio;

int main() {
    io_service service;
    std::string str = std::string("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n ......");

    ip::tcp::acceptor my_acceptor{ service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), 6767) };
    ip::tcp::socket my_socket{ service };
    my_acceptor.async_accept(my_socket, [&my_socket, &str](boost::system::error_code ec) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cerr << "Oops: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "connected " << std::endl;

            async_write(my_socket, boost::asio::buffer(str), [&my_socket](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t) {
                if (ec) {
                    std::cerr << "Oops: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                } else {
                    std::cout << "Data written" << std::endl;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    service.run();
}
```